# Nodejs error: invalid: inherits@2.0.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/inherits@2

Tags: node.js, centos, npm

I seem to have two versions of inherits@2.0.0, although when I tried using `npm dedupe` it didn't remove the invalid version. How do I fix this?

> ├── inherits@2.0.0
>   ├── inherits@2.0.0 (inherits@2) invalid

```
> npm ERR! invalid: inherits@2.0.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/inherits@2
> npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i took the easy out.

`rm -rf` the thing into oblivion

meh